# How to define an default Access Type for JPA2 Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Because of some strange behavior of Hibernate JPA 2 Meta Model Generator, I need to set the Access Type for all of my Entities to `AccessType.FIELD`. - Because I do not want to add an `@Access` Annotation to every class I am asking for an Way to set the default Access Type.

Up to now I tryed it with this `orm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <access>FIELD</access>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>        
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
```

But this seems to be ignored, the generator uses PROPERTY access as default.

When I add this lines to {{orm.xml}}:

```
<access>FIELD</access>
<entity class="domain.Banner"></entity>
<entity class="domain.Stuff"></entity>
...
```

The generator start to pay respect to the fields (and not the properties), but this is more worse then the annotation way.

So my question is: how to set the default AccessType?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 3.6 with JPA 2.0 and mostly using field access in all my entities. The metamodel generator has not exhibited any issues. What exactly is the problem that you have with the metamodel generator?

Comment: @edalorzo: I doing the same in a Spring Roo Environment, and even if the entity has no Roo annotations Hibernate pay attention only to the properties, but not the fiels (except if I a @Access Annotation)

Comment: Are you putting the JPA annotations on fields or getter/setters? If you put them on getter/setters JPA will use the property access type.

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh: The annotations are on the fields. But it is a spring roo application, and for some reason the auto detections field/property seams not to work correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to find a solution to your problem? I'm not sure if hibernate and JPA support this, but you may be able to use package-level annotations. Here's an example for type definitions from http://www.ctrlspace.ca/?p=10

```
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "trim", typeClass = TrimmedString.class) })  
@FilterDefs({  
@FilterDef(name = "ACTIVE_FILTER", defaultCondition = "((end_date is null) or (end_date >= current_date))"),  
@FilterDef(name = "HISTORICAL_FILTER", defaultCondition = "(end_date < current_date)")})  
package com.ctrlspace.model;  

import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDefs;  
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;  
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;  

import com.ctrlspace.type.TrimmedString;
```